trying to launch an app via package manager on Android 12. The code works for Android 8 and 9 but not for 12
I am using Nativescript 8.4 and I am trying to launch an application that does a very specific task. The following code works correctly on Android 8 and 9 but not on version 12:
My AndroidManifest.xml sets the intent-filter with the correct permissions (at least for Android 8 and 9)
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

Here is the code that successfully launches the App for Android 8 and 9 but not on Android 12:
private launchApp() {
  const cntxt = Utils.android.getApplicationContext();
  const pm = cntxt.getPackageManager();
  const packageName = "com.vms.android.theAppThtatIamTryingToInterface";
  let intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
  if (intent){ // Add extra data 
      // works on Android 8 and 9 but not on 12
    intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra("mode", 0); //start dex mode         
    console.log('Before starting intent');
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", this.getTransaction());
    context.startActivity(intent);
  }else{
      console.log("Intent could not be created for", packageName);
  }
}

The call to pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName) returns null on Android 12 but correctly returns the intent for Android 8 and 9
What am I missing?
I have tried getting the context from Utils.android.getApplicationContext() instead of the applicationModule.android.context but that did not work.
Additionally, I changed app.gradle to a higher SDK but that did not work either:
android {
   compileSdkVersion 32
   buildToolsVersion "32.0.0"
   ndkVersion ""

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 32

    // Version Information
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"

    generatedDensities = []
  }

  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}

